# Scroll View content size in ipad Universal app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-universal-app

I set the Scroll view size to scroll up the content if they hide behind the Keypad. Its a universal app now I am doing same for iPad.

What would be the height/width of ipad screen and How do I set these for ipad?

code to check if its Ipad or Iphone

```
BOOL isiPhone = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
if (isiPhone)
           // write code
```

these are variable to set.

```
#define SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT 460
#define SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH  320
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iPad    768*1004
iPhone  320*480**

I think it is better way to get height and width of iPad/iPhone

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Width %f",width);
    NSLog(@"Height %f",height);
}
else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Width %f",width);
    NSLog(@"Height %f",height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here how to manage the keyboard appearance.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

A nicer way to do it is with `scrollView.contentInset`